# What is the difference between parse() and as.expression() in r

Tags: r

Taking a simple example.

```
expr <- 'mpg*2 + cyl*3 + disp*4'
```

I convert `expr` as an expression and evaluate it.

```
expr2 <- parse(text = expr)
class(expr2)
mtcars %>% mutate(new_var = eval(expr2))
```

Then I tried another way, but the `new_var` is just a character vector.

```
expr3 <- as.expression(expr)
class(expr3)
mtcars %>% mutate(new_var = eval(expr3))
```

`eval` help document  said that:

> Evaluate an R expression in a specified environment.

Both `expr2` and `expr3` were expression, why the result was different.

`parse` help document said that:

> parse() returns the parsed but unevaluated expressions in an expression, a “list” of calls.

I could not tell from what is **parsed** and what is **unevaluated**.

Could anyone explain this?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`parse` creates an expression from a text input, this is probably what you expect.

From the [as.expression documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/expression), `as.expression` tries to coerce its arguments to an expression.

What does this mean?

```r
test <- 1
expr <- parse(text="test + 1")
expr 
#> expression(test + 1)
eval(expr)
#> [1] 2

expr <- as.expression("test + 1")
expr
#> expression("test + 1")
eval(expr)
#> [1] "test + 1"

expr <- as.expression(test+1)
expr
#> expression(2)
eval(expr)
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you can see a text argument isn't coercible because it wasn't parsed, so it remains unchanged.

Comment: Yep, those  quotation marks in the returned values are important!